# Pytorch broadcasting not working as expected

Tags: python, pytorch, array-broadcasting

I am in the early stages of learning Pytorch for deep learning and have come across something I don't understand. I have written a very simple script to just make sure I fully understand the broadcasting mechanism, but I am getting an error that I find confusing.

```py
import torch

X = torch.tensor([[1,5,2,7],[8,2,5,3]])
Y = torch.tensor([[2,9],[11,4],[9,2],[22,7]])

print(X.shape, Y.shape)
```

outputs

```
>>> torch.Size([2, 4]) torch.Size([4, 2])
```

But when I try to execute a basic mathematical operation on these tensors, where I would expect the broadcasting mechanism to bring them to the same size, I get the following error.

```
print(X + Y)
```

outputs

```
RuntimeError                              Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-7-e4a642f73c42> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 X + Y

RuntimeError: The size of tensor a (4) must match the size of tensor b (2) at non-singleton dimension 1
```

All the explanations I have seen say that the matrices simply need to be compatible for matrix multiplication. which to my knowledge in this case they are.

X = 2x4
Y = 4x2

The amount of rows to amount of columns are the same so I don't understand the error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, in PyTorch you do need to use `matmul()` for matrix multiplication. (I assume you are talking about multiplication even though your example uses `+`)

```py
print(torch.matmul(X,  Y))
```

Output:

```
tensor([[229,  82],
        [149, 111]])
```

Second, this has nothing to do with broadcasting. Broadcasting is when you you have an operation that requires two tensors to be of compatible shape (usually the same) and they are not but it is possible to *broadcast* one of them to an equivalent shape so they are compatible.

An example from the [broadcasting documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html):

```py
x=torch.empty(5,1,4,1)
y=torch.empty(  3,1,1)
(x+y).size()
```

Output:

```
torch.Size([5, 3, 4, 1])
```

Another example would be adding an additional outer dimension to X in your example:

```py
X = torch.tensor([[[1,5,2,7],[8,2,5,3]]])
Y = torch.tensor([[2,9],[11,4],[9,2],[22,7]])

print(X.shape, Y.shape)
```

```
torch.Size([1, 2, 4]) torch.Size([4, 2])
```

But `matmul()` still works as Y is broadcasted to a (1,4,2) tensor (by prepending the so called batch-dimension) leading to a (1,2,2) tensor:

```py
print(torch.matmul(X,  Y).shape)
```

Output:

```
torch.Size([1, 2, 2])
```

Comment: I am aware I am not doing matrix multiplication. But in my research on why I am getting an error said that in order for broadcasting to take place, the sizes must be compatible for matrix multiplication. But I am simply trying to have broadcasting make these shapes compatible for elementwise operations.

Comment: Saying that broadcasting generally makes sizes compatible for matrix multiplication is simply wrong. Broadcasting has way broader applications. 
But broadcasting does not work when there is no equivalent shape that would work in the given application. A (2,4) tensor cannot be implicitly converted into an equivalent (4,2) tensor. These have completely different meanings. You can explicitly reshape a (4,2) tensor into a (2,4) tensor but then YOU are saying that this conversion makes sense in your application. Python cannot just assume that (as it is generally wrong without further information).